# How does one access the twilio phone number that was purchased in twilio?

Tags: twilio

I purchased a twilio account (pay as you go, funded the account).

Then I bought one of their (twilio's) phone numbers to use as the "from" number when sending sms text messages. That transaction went fine.

I then return to my twilio dashboard. HOW DO YOU ACCESS YOUR LIST OF PURCHASED TWILIO PHONE NUMBERS???

I see no way to "manage phone numbers" anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You want to visit the [phone numbers section of the console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming). You can follow that link, or, if you are on the console home page look to the left of your screen. There's a sidebar that has a circle with three horizontal dots in it. Click that circle and the sidebar will open up showing you all of the sections of the console. Under *Super Network* you will find *Phone Numbers*.

Comment: Sounds like three dots are not a hamburger, google cloud console got it right, cheers :-).

Comment: I don't know the reasons, but we decided that the [meatball menu](https://syndicode.com/2018/04/26/know-your-site-menu/) was the correct choice here!

Comment: No problem, and sorry you had to deal with this frustration.